# Orchard: Using InfosetPart to store "Data" in orchard_framework_contentitemversionrecord

Tags: orchardcms

After reading [Bertrand Le Roy's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2013/11/04/the-shift-how-orchard-painlessly-shifted-to-document-storage-and-how-it-ll-affect-you.aspx) about the shift to document storage, the InfosetPart in Orchard 1.8 and understanding some of the upgraded Modules in Orchard 1.8 "1.x" source code i have successfully made some of my modules compatible with Orchard 1.8.

But i am having a hard time understanding how the same scheme of document storage would work for ContentPartVersionRecord types so that my content part's data start persisting in "Data" column of orchard_framework_contentitemversionrecord table.

I would be highly thankful for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store your data versioned in the infoset just use the overload of Store/Retrieve in your part that lets you set `versioned = true`, e.g.:

```
Store<TPart, TProperty>(this TPart contentPart, Expression<Func<TPart, TProperty>> targetExpression, TProperty value, bool versioned = false)
```